# Rewriting M in terms of omega?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, vectors, transpose

Given a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then show that we can express $\sum_{k} \omega_kv^2_k$ as a matrix product of the form $v^TMv$. Give an expression for $M$ in terms of $\omega = [\omega_1 ... \omega_n]^T$.

I understand that here, the product of a row vector, matrix, and column vector (in that order) is a scalar. However, how do I write $M$ in terms of $\omega = [\omega_1 ... \omega_n]^T$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that in general, we have
$$
v^TMv = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n m_{ij} v_i v_j.
$$
I would recommend that you verify this for the cases $n = 2,3$. Now, notice that the expression $\sum_k \omega_k v_k^2$ contains no terms of the form $\alpha\,v_iv_j$ (for a scalar $\alpha$).

Comment: Would I have to look into the trace of the matrix M? Omega would be some scalar value, and then the vector values (v_k)^2 would be the diagonal values? Please let me know if this is the correct train of thought.

Comment: I don't know why you're talking about the trace of $M$. What is true is that $M$ needs to be a *diagonal* matrix. The entries of $M$ should not use the entries of $v$ in any way